# How can I get unlimited information from pstree?

Tags: linux, process, proc

I am using `pstree` to watch a sequence of scripts and even when using `-pla`, I get shortened versions of arguments and script names. As an example:

```
sshd,13431
  └─bash,13432
      └─runJobs.sh,18780 ./runJobs.sh
          └─job1.sh,18781 ./job1.sh /path/to/location/of/some/file/that/I/need/to/see/file1.txt /path/to/the/location/of/some/other/file/that/I/need/to/see/file2.txt /path/to/yet/another/location/of/some/other/file/that/I/also/need/to/see/file3.txt/yet/another/long/path/to/a/4th/locatio
              └─veryLongNameFor,18782 ./veryLongNameForJob2.sh Argument1_is_very_long arg2_is_also_quite_long The_name_for_arg3_is_even_longer
                  └─sleep,18783 1000
```

As you can see `verLongNameForJob2.sh` is trimmed, I don't get the full path for `/yet/another/long/path/to/a/4th/location/that/I/need/to/lookAt/file4.txt` and I also get `/path/to/yet/another/location/of/some/other/file/that/I/also/need/to/see/file3.txt` concatenated with `/yet/another/long/path/to/a/4th/location/that/I/need/to/lookAt/file4.txt`. How can I get full script names along with full argument names without concatenation even if they are very long?

Below are the scripts I used for this:

**runJobs.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
### contents of 'runJobs.sh'

arg1=/path/to/location/of/some/file/that/I/need/to/see/file1.txt
arg2=/path/to/the/location/of/some/other/file/that/I/need/to/see/file2.txt
arg3=/path/to/yet/another/location/of/some/other/file/that/I/also/need/to/see/file3.txt
arg4=/yet/another/long/path/to/a/4th/location/that/I/need/to/lookAt/file4.txt

./job1.sh $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4
```

**job1.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
### contents of job1.sh

arg1=Argument1_is_very_long 
arg2=arg2_is_also_quite_long
arg3=The_name_for_arg3_is_even_longer

./veryLongNameForJob2.sh $arg1 $arg2 $arg3
```

**veryLongNameForJob2.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
### contents of 'veryLongNameForJob2.sh'

sleep 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the issue with `pstree` on my Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I needed way longer paths, but still.

Tools like `pstree` use `/proc` to gather information, so read `/proc/<PID>/cmdline`. It's a bad luck if the information is truncated there. But it may be that you hit the limit of your `pstree` implementation only.

**In my case `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` was not trimmed when I crossed the limit in `pstree`.**

Another good news is the arguments in `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` are separated with NULL characters (`0x00`).